# custom yum repo not showing rpm

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, rhel, repository

I have a yum repository I've set up where I store custom rpms.
I have no problem finding information about other packages that were built and stored in this custom repo.

```
#yum  --disablerepo=rhui-us-east-rhel-server-1y,epel,epel-testing --enablerepo=customrepo install php53-pecl-xdebug

 php53-pecl-xdebug                   x86_64                   2.2.1-2  customrepo                      132 k
```

No problem.

Now I drop somerpm.rpm in centos/repo/5/noarch, run createrepo --update . in this directory and try the same command, and yet it shows no results.

I tried running createrepo --update in the root of the repo as well, but that did not work either (I'm actually not sure where to run it and if it needs a repodata directory in each subdir).

```
[root@reposerver mnt]# ls -l /var/www/repo/ 
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  203 Jun  8 00:13 REPO_README
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 10  2011 centos
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:02 repodata
[root@reposerver mnt]# ls -l /var/www/repo/centos/5/
SRPMS/    i386/     noarch/   repodata/ x86_64/   
[root@reposerver mnt]# ls -l /var/www/repo/centos/5/noarch/
total 7324
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1622 Jun 28  2011 compat-php-5.1.6-1.noarch.rpm
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 18 19:55 repodata
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1066928 Oct 18 19:54 salt-0.10.3-1.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6363197 Oct 18 19:54 salt-0.10.3-1.src.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   21822 Oct 18 19:54 salt-master-0.10.3-1.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14294 Oct 18 19:54 salt-minion-0.10.3-1.noarch.rpm
```

I also tried adding the exactarch=0 flag to my repo config to ignore arch restrictions and this did not work either, it was a shot in the dark, since my rpm is noarch, it should show regardless.

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/mycompany.repo 
[mycompany]
name=mycompany custom repo
baseurl=http://config/repo/centos/5/$basearch
enabled=1
exactarch=0
```

I'm at a loss at this point. Usually createrepo --update does the trick, but for some reason it cannot find the new rpms.

```
 repo]# find . -type f -name "*.gz" | xargs  zcat | grep salt-minion
```

returns results as well, so it's definitely in the repo data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`yum clean all` on the server I was trying to install on worked.
Also make sure to do createrepo --update on the specific subdir instead of the root of the repo.